# How to prevent self (recursive) selection for FK / MTM fields in the Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Given a model with ForeignKeyField (FKF) or ManyToManyField (MTMF) fields with a foreignkey to 'self' how can I prevent *self* (recursive) selection within the Django Admin (admin).

In short, it should be possible to *prevent* self (recursive) selection of a model instance in the admin. This applies when editing existing instances of a model, not creating new instances.

For example, take the following model for an article in a news app;

```
class Article(models.Model):           
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    related_articles = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

If there are 3 `Article` instances (title: a1-3), when editing an existing `Article` instance via the admin the `related_articles` field is represented by default by a html (multiple)select box which provides a list of ALL articles (`Article.objects.all()`). The user should only see and be able to select `Article` instances other than itself, e.g. When editing `Article` a1, `related_articles` available to select = a2, a3.

I can currently see 3 potential to ways to do this, in order of decreasing preference;

1. Provide a way to set the queryset providing available choices in the admin form field for the `related_articles` (via an exclude query filter, e.g. `Article.objects.filter(~Q(id__iexact=self.id))` to exclude the current instance being edited from the list of related_articles a user can see and select from. Creation/setting of the queryset to use could occur within the constructor (`__init__`) of a custom `Article ModelForm`, or, via some kind of dynamic `limit_choices_to Model` option. This would require a way to grab the instance being edited to use for filtering.
2. Override the `save_model` function of the `Article Model` or `ModelAdmin` class to check for and remove itself from the `related_articles` before saving the instance. This still means that admin users can see and select all articles including the instance being edited (for existing articles).
3. Filter out self references when required for use outside the admin, e.g. templates.

The ideal solution (1) is currently possible to do via custom model forms outside of the admin as it's possible to pass in a filtered queryset variable for the instance being edited to the model form constructor. Question is, can you get at the `Article` instance, i.e. 'self' being edited the admin before the form is created to do the same thing.

It could be I am going about this the wrong way, but if your allowed to define a FKF / MTMF to the same model then there should be a way to have the admin - *do the right thing* - and prevent a user from selecting itself by excluding it in the list of available choices.

**Note:** Solution 2 and 3 are possible to do now and are provided to try and avoid getting these as answers, ideally i'd like to get an answer to solution 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom ModelForm in the admin (by setting [the "form" attribute of your ModelAdmin subclass](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)).  So you do it the same way in the admin as you would anywhere else.

Comment: *Technically*, I know why [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) cannot do this. Practically, I don't understand why it has never been implemented.

Comment: @kojiro - simple things should be simple, advanced things should be possible. Not every possible feature has to be squeezed into limit_choices_to, precisely because you can always write your own ModelForm code to do whatever you want. If you have a suggestion for intuitive syntax for adding this to limit_choices_to without making it more complex, you're welcome to open a ticket with patch and propose it.

Answer (score 10):

Carl is correct, here's a cut and paste code sample that would go in `admin.py`

I find navigating the Django relationships can be tricky if you don't have a solid grasp, and a living example can be worth 1000 time more than a "go read this" (not that you don't need to understand what is happening).

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myManyToManyField'].queryset = MyModel.objects.exclude(
            id__exact=self.instance.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also override the `get_form` method of the ModelAdmin like so:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Modify the fields in the form that are self-referential by
    removing self instance from queryset
    """
    form = super().get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
    # obj won't exist yet for create page
    if obj:
        # Finds fieldnames of related fields whose model is self
        rmself_fields = [f.name for f in self.model._meta.get_fields() if (
            f.concrete and f.is_relation and f.related_model is self.model)]
        for fieldname in rmself_fields:
            form.base_fields[fieldname]._queryset =
                form.base_fields[fieldname]._queryset.exclude(id=obj.id)
    return form
```

Note that this is a on-size-fits-all solution that automatically finds self-referencing model fields and removes self from all of them :-)

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution of checking at `save()` time:

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # call full_clean() that in turn will call clean()
        self.full_clean()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        obj = self
        parents = set()
        while obj is not None:
            if obj in parents:
                raise ValidationError('Loop error', code='infinite_loop')
            parents.add(obj)
            obj = obj.parent
```