# How do I prevent a ManyToManyField('self') from linked an object to itself?

Tags: django, django-models

Consider this model (simplified for this question):

```
class SecretAgentName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    aliases = ManyToManyField('self')
```

I have three names, `"James Bond"`, `"007"` and `"Jason Bourne"`. `"James Bond"` and `"007"` are aliases of each other.

This works exactly like I want it to, except for the fact that every instance can also be an alias of itself. This I want to prevent. So, there can be many SecretAgentNames, all can be aliases of each other as long as `"James Bond"` does not show up as an alias for `"James Bond"`.

Can I prevent this in the model definition? If not, can I prevent it anywhere else, preferably so that the Django Admin understands it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent self (recursive) selection for FK / MTM fields in the Django Admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869856/how-to-prevent-self-recursive-selection-for-fk-mtm-fields-in-the-django-admin)

Comment: The post referenced by Dominic Rodger offers a solution on a form level. I was hoping for a solution that is part of the model. Possible something similar to or using `limit_choices_to`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're ERD is off here. I would sugest Secret Agent Name as a parent of Aliasses, and store all names in Alliasses, leaving only meta in Secret Agent Names. Then all you need is a many-to-one relationship from Alliasses to Secret Agent Names.