# Django Admin - Filter Choice Field based on current object being edited

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am attempting to exclude the current object being edited from a choice field to select a parent object from the same model. For example:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

class RelationForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Ingredient.objects.exclude(id=current_ingredient_id))  

    def save(self, commit=True):
        parent = self.cleaned_data.get('parent', None)
        # ...do something with extra_field here...
        return super(RelationForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = IngredientRelations
        exclude = ['description']

@admin.register(Ingredient)
class IngredientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = RelationForm

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
             'fields': ('name', 'slug', 'description', 'parent',),
        }),
    )
```

The difficult comes from getting the current object being edited and then getting its primary key in the RelationForm for the queryset argument.

I have tried using [ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/) and [ModelAdmin.formfield_for_choice_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/) in IngredientAdmin with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical method to do this is by updating the `queryset` in the `__init__` method using currently edited instance id.

```
class RelationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RelationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.id:
            self.fields['parent'].queryset = Ingredient.objects.exclude(id=self.instance.id)

    class Meta:
        model = IngredientRelations
        exclude = ['description']
```

originally seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1869917/484127