# Patient user can be Responsible from himself - Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

First of all I would like to say that I am extremely new to Django and Python.

I am writing an application using Django 2.0. I have two inheritances to the ***user***: the ***patient*** and ***responsible***. A ***patient*** needs a ***user*** to exist and a ***responsible***  needs a ***patient*** to exist. A ***responsible***  may have several ***patients*** but one ***patient*** may only have one ***responsible***.

However I am having the following problem: A patient can not be responsible for himself and currently this happens. How can I stop this from happening?

**patient model:**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='patient',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
(...)
```

**responsible model:**

```
class Responsible(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            limit_choices_to=Q(patient=None))
patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As you can see I'm using the "limit_choices_to" but it causes all users who are patients are not listed in the time I create a new responsible.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869856/how-to-prevent-self-recursive-selection-for-fk-mtm-fields-in-the-django-admi

Comment: @AMG I have managed to resolve this differently, as per the comment below. Thanks for your help anyway, as it guided me through the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this as follows:

In my **responsible model** i added the following lines:

```
    def clean(self):
    if self.user == self.patient.user:
        raise ValidationError(_("A patient can not be responsible for himself"))
```

So now it is no longer possible for a patient to be responsible for himself.